# Proof by contradiction, fields

Tags: field-theory, proof-writing

Given the field $\mathbb{K}:=\{a+b\sqrt{2}: a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$, how would I prove that every $x\in \mathbb{K}$ is uniquely representable in this way: $x=a+b\sqrt{2}$, with $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$?

I think it would be a proof by contradiction.

So, let's assume there are two different elements $x_1$, $x_2\in\mathbb{K}$ with $x_1=a+b\sqrt{2}$ and $x_2=a+b\sqrt{2}$.

But how do I go from here?

Comment: I think you have your ideas backwards. What you're meant to argue is that if $x = a_1+b_1\sqrt{2}$ and $x = a_2+b_2\sqrt{2}$, then $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$. This means that there is **only** one way to write an element.

Comment: But wouldn't that be the same? In my version the x differ and in your version the a's and b's. Either way it will prove the same thing, or am I wrong?

Comment: You're incorrect I'm afraid.

Comment: @Arthur You're saying $a+b\sqrt{2}$ equals two potentially different numbers, Cameron is saying a number $x$ can be written as $a+b\sqrt{2}$ in two different ways.

Comment: Ok, now I see my mistake, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, what you need to do is to take an element x, with two representations :

$$x = a+b\sqrt{2} = c+d\sqrt{2}$$

Then,

$$(a-c) = (d-b)\sqrt{2}$$

if $d \neq b$, you get

$$\frac{a-c}{d-b}=\sqrt{2}$$

$\sqrt{2}$ would be rationnal, so $b=d$, and $a=c$.

The representation of x is then unique